# Multiple category output in auto generated entry title

Tags: titles, auto-generate, post

I have a single category field (named category) in my section and I am looking to use the auto-generated title to keep these entries titled consistently. I have had success outputting the first category selection into the entry field but I can't seem to grab multiple selections. I have tried a for loop and I can of course getting working on a template but I am thinking the syntax must be different for the auto generated title field.

Here is an example of the tree I am working with.

- Category One

  - Sub Cat One
  - Sub Cat Two

In a example entry I will have Sub Cat One selected and of course Category One since it is an ancestor of the Sub Cat One. I would like to output something like (Category One / Sub Cat One) in the entry title but I either get no results or just the first one. I have tried the following code:

```
{% for categoryList in category %}{{categoryList.title}}{% if loop.index < loop.length %}/{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

and

```
{category.first().title}
```

Which of course contains only the first selected category title.

How do you output more than one category selection in an entry title field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the single brace tag syntax within your URL Format field:

```
{category.first().title}
```

that’s actually a shortcut for this:

```
{{ object.category.first().title }}
```

So, `object` is the actual variable name that you can use to refer to your entry, when you want to use the normal Twig tags `{{ ... }}` and `{% ... %}`.

```
{% for categoryList in object.category %}{{ categoryList.title }}{% if not loop.last %}/{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It works of course!! Awesome and good to know.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could also use Twig's [join filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/join.html) instead of the for loop:

```
{{ object.category | join('/') }}
```